# Authentication using Android Volley and ASP .NET Web API

Tags: android, asp.net, authorization, android-volley

I have sent a volley request and got AccessToken, then ovveride getheaders() method and put token on the headers:

```
private void login(String username,String password)
    {
        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        JSONObject jsonArrayToken = null;

                        try {                   
                            jsonArrayToken = response.getJSONObject("token");


                                token =  jsonArrayToken.getString("AccessToken");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                        

                }
        )
        {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String auth = "Bearer " + token;
                headers.put("Authorization", auth);
                return headers;
            }
        };              
        requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }
```

but i can't accsses my Authorized Method

```
[Authorize]
public void Test()
{

}
```

can anyone give me tips how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that you got the access token? Post its value if available

Comment: pIPDaCNXDADh83_bWC7C7UmyxTZlmGmogXeSxMYCv341J11bBRL-nlA7E-CDXXPGWug12lFUHptDzhqzmfgGgVLxnogU3ttCaDetxQj5r1hJo9kBmgu9qfE-7gbhrCwmfmILmxRO9vnu3318hp23V-IhnvWXHJeodA6C2on5tvP_Yd5VDHRuGkJyKIFkgjXvEgxG0L_6xlcE6PxkRSLySUSylKfyxlIBBoUX9qH8sQs

Comment: Can you post the complete response? If I remember correctly, you must provide grant_type="password" together with user&pass to get the access token

Comment: Yes i did so . var tokenModel = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"grant_type", "password"},
                {"username", username},
                {"password", password},
            };

            var response = await CallApiTask("api/authtoken", tokenModel);

Comment: and response   token:Object
AccessToken
:
"ocAOBlEqNhXPZlGeofLeEH2BklbFasyiRjbei7WqaoQj25eiA692nYs6Gjlng89hI74zSQ7oMhE2YSSZ_i55_grSeAYPcc7AkflhJy8PBZYY5rzlSlC8TUKRj0XHhN9ELj_c_blbhtbBeMwdffNleYjyuqG16jBsk2r05NHvyYEB49D4i6LkDSmlV2weeV3_XcjWkUVSbnSuROM6SOxr0JQldbSSBjSSGdWbZi1Nknc"
Expires
:
"/Date(1462790509000)/"
ExpiresIn
:
1209599
Issued
:
"/Date(1461580909000)/"
TokenType
:
"bearer"

Comment: i have tested with ajax request and works  but with android volley not.

Comment: Pls set breakpoint at the line "headers.put("Authorization", auth);", then start debugging and check the actual value of "auth" variable

Comment: One more thing, you only need `getHeaders` with that token for other Volley requests. The login request does not need

Comment: Yes i did so and it works!!! thanks!